# Renaming Sheets with loop function

Tags: vba, loops, rename

I'm trying to rename all sheets and then put them in alphabetical order.
I'm getting the error Method 'Name' of object'_Worksheet' failed.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated

```
Sub Rename()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
            Range("S4").Select
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT($A$4,LEN($A$4)-16)),"","","""")"
            str = ws.Range("S4").Value
            ws.Name = str
            
        End If
        
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the value at `$A$4` you are using?

Comment: Why use `Select` and `ActiveCell` rather than directly working with the range object? Also -- are you sure that you are selecting `S4` from the correct worksheet? `ws.Range("S4")` might make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sub Rename()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, str As String
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
            ws.Range("S4") = "=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT($A$4,LEN($A$4)-16)),"","","""")"
            str = ws.Range("S4").Value
            ws.Name = str
        End If
        
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: perhaps consider another variable name than `str`, which is shadowing the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code could be like this. Note that [there are restrictions for naming sheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-worksheet-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9) and sheet names cannot be repeated. So I recommend using `Debug.Print` when debugging code (included in the code).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Rename()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, txt As String, a As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    
    ReDim a(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) As String
    i = 0
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
            txt = ws.Range("A4").Text
            txt = Replace(Trim(Right(txt, Len(txt) - 16)), ",", "") 'we don't know what is in A4, so you need to tweak it
            Debug.Print "Trying to rename sheet '" & ws.Name & "' to '" & txt & "'..."
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Name = txt
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print vbTab & "FAILED to rename the sheet '" & ws.Name & "' to '" & txt & "'"
            Else
                i = i + 1
                a(i) = txt
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next ws
    
    If i > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve a(1 To i)
        
        ' bubble sort sheets names
        For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
            For j = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
                If a(i) < a(j) Then
                    txt = a(i): a(i) = a(j): a(j) = txt
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        
        ' rearrange the sheets
        For i = UBound(a) To LBound(a) Step -1
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(a(i)).Move Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "No sheets renamed", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```